# resample dataframe with python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, resampling, datetimeindex

I need to resample a dataframe using pandas.DataFrame.resample function like this :

```
data.set_index('TIMESTAMP').resample('24min', how='sum')
```

This works without no problem, but when I try call the fucntion with 'xmin" where x is a general argment

```
  data.set_index('TIMESTAMP').resample('xmin', how='sum')
```

It cannot works

Any idea please?

Thank you

**EDIT**

```
def ratio_activ_equip(data, date_deb, date_fin, step):      

 # filtre_site(data, site)
filtre_date(data, date_deb, date_fin)
xmin = 'stepmin'
data.set_index('TIMESTAMP').resample(xmin, how='sum')
res = data.iloc[:,1:10] = data.iloc[:,1:10].divide(data.sum(axis=1), axis=0)
res = data
return res
```

**EDIT2**

```
def ratio_activ_equip(data, date_deb, date_fin, step):       #
     # filtre_site(data, site)
    filtre_date(data, date_deb, date_fin)
    #step = 10
    xmin = str(step) + 'min'
    data = data.set_index('TIMESTAMP').resample(xmin, how='sum')
    data.set_index('TIMESTAMP').resample(xmin, how='sum')
    res = data.iloc[:,1:10] = data.iloc[:,1:10].divide(data.sum(axis=1), axis=0)
    res = data
    return res
```

When I call this fucntion like this :

```
res = ratio_activ_equip(y, '2016-05-10 22:00:00', '2016-05-14 22:00:00', 30)
```

I get this error :

> ```
> KeyError: 'TIMESTAMP'
> ```

Any idea please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you need pass variable `xmin`:

```
xmin = '24min'
data.set_index('TIMESTAMP').resample(xmin, how='sum')
```

More general is convert `int` value to `str` and add substring `min`:

```
step = 10
xmin = str(step) + 'min'
data = data.set_index('TIMESTAMP').resample(xmin, how='sum')
```

---

```
step = 10
data = data.set_index('TIMESTAMP').resample(str(step) + 'min', how='sum')
```

Comment: Thank you jezrael, but I need to make it more generally, I edit my post.

Comment: how can I use step variable to resample the dataframe in this case?

Comment: Phhhooo, `resample` have not argument `stepmin`. Do you need resample from `1Min` to `24Min` ?

Comment: I depends the case, it can be even 500 minutes

Comment: There is typo, you need remove `data.set_index('TIMESTAMP').resample(xmin, how='sum')`